# Fragment Menu getting slow while changing one fragment to other

Tags: android, android-fragments

![Below is the screen shot which will explain the problem that i am facing][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI84Y.png

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      new loadMoreListView().execute();

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_standings, container, false);
    list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list1);

    new loadMoreListView().execute();
    return rootView;



}
```

I am trying to load some data from server using Json . The real problem i am facing is that whenever i click in side menu items , it will get lagged , like in the photo . Can anyone help me in these issue . I am loading data from server in  async task

Answer (score 0):

The SDK has a great utility, Traceview, for finding bottle-necks like the one you describe. Check out [profiling with traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)